# Fabric Digits - userID in DGTContactsFetcher is always nil for users on Digits

Tags: twitter-digits, google-fabric, fabric-digits

we have an issue we dont know how to deal with, we started using DIGITS from fabric to login users with SMS, the login works fine we get the usersID's that have installed the app using the lookupContactMatches function. 
but when we use

```
    Digits.sharedInstance().createContactsFetcher().fetchContactsOnly(inApp: false, withCompletion: { [weak self] (contact, error) in
```

we get all the users contacts but none of them obtain a digit userID. so basically we cant know who from the user contacts has the app. i couldn't find any information or a way to contact Digits from fabric, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. You can always contact us via support(at)fabric(dot)io and there should be a link to that in the bottom-left corner of your Fabric dashboard. Are you paging through all the results and just the first contacts received?

Comment: hi mike thanks for responding, in the lookForMatches im going thru all the cursos and im getting the results just fine, but in fetchContactsOnly im getting all of my contacts but none of them has userID although the lookForMatches before that did found them. as i understand from the documantion  the contactFethcher should populate the userID if the other contact was found in matches and have the application installed and logged in.